# React Native Android - Error while running react-native run-android the first time

Tags: android, build.gradle, react-native

I am new to react-native. After creating the project, I was trying to run on android with this command.

```
react-native run-android
```

I ran into some " Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081". The screenshot of the terminal(command prompt) is here :
[image: Screenshot of the terminal]

I have all java, Android Studio installed. I have also added the ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME environment variable and platform-tools in Path. I have also build the project in Android Studio. Please help me solving this error.

Comment: Can you post your Gradle and the JDK versions?

Comment: Grade version 6.2 and jdk version 14.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle 6.2 does not support JDK 14. You have to upgrade your Gradle version to 6.3 or later.

Comment: **Thanks a lot** for help. I upgraded the Gradle version and react-native builded the apk.